# Can't retrieve a ssmParameter for configure a CodePipeline

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to configure a CodePipeline using GitHub as a source stage, in order to do that, I configured my GitHub OAuth token using the Secrets Manager:

```
const oauth = new SecretParameter(this, 'GitHubOAuthToken', {
  ssmParameter: 'github-token'
})

new codepipeline.GitHubSourceAction(this, 'GitHubSource', {
  stage: sourceStage,
  owner: 'owner',
  repo: 'repo',
  branch: 'master',
  oauthToken: new Secret(oauth)
})
```

But when I try to deploy the stack `cdk deploy` I get:

> ValidationError: Unable to fetch parameters [github-token] from parameter store for this account.
>   Unable to fetch parameters [github-token] from parameter store for this account.

I've also tried to add permissions to the pipeline

```
pipeline.role.addToPolicy(
  new PolicyStatement()
    .addAllResources()
    .addAction('secretsmanager:GetSecretValue')
)
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I got confused with Secrets Manager and Parameter Store, I saved my token to the Parameter instead and it worked just fine.